# Android gradle plugin error

Tags: android, plugins, gradle

I tried importing a project but got this error. I tried the auto-update to upgrade my gradle plugin but it didn't work. [Android gradle plugin error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgrnu.png)

Do I need to make changes in build.gradle project file?
Is there any specific way to update my gradle plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In ur build.gradle use this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0'
```

and try to rebuild the project. If the gradle is present the build is success, otherwise it will ask to update the gradle plugin and click on it.So, It will automatically updates and completes build.

Comment: I will give it a try. I tried the automatic update but it couldn't find any resources and automatic build failed.